# Remove Target Object reference from constraint with python

Tags: python, scripting, constraints

I know how to set a constraint target via Python:

```
ob = bpy.data.objects["RightArmIKDataPoint"]
bpy.data.objects["MySkeleton"].pose.bones["RightArmIK"].constraints["MocapHook"].target = ob
```

However, I do not know **how to unset this**. I don't know what set the target to to be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the the `target` property to `None` to clear the target field.

So in your example it would be:

```
...constraints["MocapHook"].target = None
```